# How to convert 'time' from an HTML textbox to sql time?

Tags: java, html, mysql, time

I have this text box in HTML.

```
<input id="textinput" name="textTime" type="time"  class="form-control input-md" >
```

The format of the input box in the browser looks like this (hh:mm AM/PM).

How do I convert this to a Time object in Java?

This code didn't work so far. It resulted an empty output

```
String timeRecorded=request.getParameter("textTime");               
 DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
 timeRecorded1 = (Date)formatter.parse(timeRecorded);
```

Comment: `hh:mm AM/PM` != `hh:mm:ss a`...

Comment: Can you tell us for what value(s) of `timeRecorded` you see the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
 SimpleDateFormat format= new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
    String yourtime= request.getParameter("textTime").toString();

    try
    {
      Date date = format.parse(yourtime);

      System.out.println(format.format(date));
    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I have edited my answer.in this answer I have assumed that value you get for timeRecorded is something like 02:22:12 AM.You have to convert request.getParameter("textTime") to string using toString() like I have done.